# Why put on Tefillin shel yad halfway?

Tags: tefilin

When we put on the tefillin shel yad, I've noticed that virtually everyone ties the tefillin up until the actual hand (like a placeholder), puts on the shel rosh, and only then finally completes the tying of the shel yad.

Why is this so? Is it merely to make the tying of the shel rosh easier (by having the left [right] hand available) or is there some deeper reasoning?

Comment: I actually finish wrapping it up on my hand before I put on Shel Rosh.

Comment: I could bring an answer from the Arizal. but I don't want to be going against the Maharsha says in Hagiga (daf 13) and in Kidushin (daf 70) and the Rashba (Shut 1:414) about publicly teaching Kabala. The answer is quite simple, but not simplistic.

Answer (score 12):

This is a case where the universal custom is according to the Arizal.

In Halacha, the Mitzvah of Tefillin shel yad is to bind it to the bicep and then wrap around the fingers three times. The three fingers do not invalidate the binding though. Therefore, according to halacha, one would put the Yad and immediately put the Rosh and only afterwards wrap around the finger.

The Arizal on the other hand holds that the seven circuits around the arm is an intrinsic part of the Mitzvah. He holds this for Kabbalistic reasons. Therefore, according to him, you must complete the wrapping of the 7 circuits before putting on the Rosh.

The universal custom is according to the Arizal.

An interesting question is if the custom was this way before the Arizal and he only gave it a reason or if the custom developed according the the Arizal's teachings. I have never looked into that.

Comment: an interesting point I learn while searching information on the way one wraps the retzuos around the middle finger : the Brisker practice to wrap around the finger before starting on the tefillah shel rosh (see Hilchos HaGra uminhag siman 38, Teshuvot Vehanhagot 1:38 and 4:10 from Rav Sternbuch shlita)

Comment: @Frank - whaaat?! I have to see that inside. Thanks for that find! And Aaron, I was taught (by a Brisker, Frank) along those lines that it is wrong to do what most people do, which is wrap it around the hand to help hold it, as that is a Hefsek, and to rather put on the Shel Rosh immediately after the 7 circuits around the arm.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it was emphasized that with the Hefsek of wrapping around the hand, one might as well just wrap around the fingers. Maybe that's why (according to Frank, and I still need to look this up) they have this Minhag.

Comment: Why is something that doesn't invalidate the binding a Hefsek? How is it worse than "pass the salt", or, better yet, Tzitzin sheEinan Miakevin if performing a second Milah immediately after the first Milah?

Comment: How universal is universal? Baladi yemenites don't.

Comment: Can you source the Arizal?

Comment: Aaron, this is not universal. I follow Minhag Frankfurt, which specifies that only the first wrapping around the arm is completed before donning the shel rosh.

Comment: The Rosh (Rabbenu Asher) was uncomfortable wrapping the arm 7 times before putting on the Shel Rosh since he felt that the original wrapping around the Bicep was MiD'Oraita and the Shel Rosh was also MiD'Oraita with the wrappings around the forearm being MiD'Rabbanan which could be placed after.

Comment: Reb Moshe is noted to have ruled like the Rosh and did not wrap around his arm more than was needed to hold the shel yad in place.

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan Orach Haim 27 says that even according to the Rosh, you are going to need to tie enough on the arm so that it stays in place. Just that the full set of wrapping on the arm is not intrinsic to the mitzvah and thus should come after completing the mitzvah on the head. But the Arizal says that the wrapping on the arm is also an intrinsic part of the mitzvah. All this is brought in the mefarshim on OH 27.

Answer (score 2):

*Mishna B'rura* 27:30 says to wrap the strap around your finger after putting on the head *t'fila*.

That said, I don't know *why* (which is what was asked), though I have always assumed it was so as to reduce delay.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. See [*Mishna B'rura* 25:38](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.25.38?lang=bi).

Answer (score 2):

While the reason is not explicitly stated in the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur10.html), it does say that you're not allowed any interruptions between putting on the shel-yad and shel-rosh. My guess is that taking the time to wrap your hand would be such an interruption.

Answer (score 1):

Its source is the Arizal.

You would need a Mekubal to answer the question.

The Beis Yosef says just to wrap around bicep then put on Shel Rosh and then finsh wrapping the rest of the arm.

Answer (score 1):

I have many source from the Ari, but the I'll bring one from Sha'ar HaKawanot, Tefilin Derush 5. That is the procedure the Ari brings down (first tying the first 7 and then the Shel Rosh).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit deep but the shel yad and ther shel rosh is like a choson and kallah with Hashem that's why we wrap 7 times around the arm like the kalah goes around the chosson 7 times. The middle finger is the holiest finger and that's why we put on a ring with the tefillin but you can only put on a ring when the choson and kallah are present (shel yad and shel rosh). That's why we take off the ring of tefillin before we remove the shel rosh after davening. So we don't have a ring thru a relationship with Hashem without him being present along with the shel yad and rosh. So only when both tefillin are on we can have the ring of tefillin (marriage ring) around out holy finger.

Comment: Does wrapping seven times around the arm really postdate circling the groom seven times?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Keeto and thanks for bringing your knowledge here. Is this your idea or did you read it somewhere? If you saw it, would be great to edit your post (click edit below it) and add the source. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!